# Good UI practice in Android, are there some sample code?

Tags: android, user-interface, ergonomics

I read carefully the good UI practice from the Google Dev Blog; http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/twitter-for-android-closer-look-at.html

and I found that they are right and twitter is an application that I really love for its User Friendly Interface ( like the Google IO app too)

As I spend most of my time developping the interface of my application, I found that a waste of time and the results are quite bad. I think that a lot of dev's like me have maybe a lack of photoshop skills and "ergonomy" ( does this word exist in english?).

I have read also on Twitter Blog that the application would be Open source: http://blog.twitter.com/2010/04/twitter-for-android-robots-like-to.html

But I havn't heard about any code release.

As there are to many things to care, regarding to the Google dev blog, I would like to know if there is an open source application that could learn me how to use all these pattern ( search bar, moving bitmaps, QuickActions, etc.)

I know that the answer to my question is not a simple line of code, but maybe an open source project or reference application to learn how to do the UI tricks as simple as they are on the Twitter app.

Thank a lot for any guide/blog/code sample.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But I havn't heard about any code
>   release.

The Twitter application has not been released as of the time of this writing.

> I would like to know if there is an
>   open source application that could
>   learn me how to use all these pattern
>   ( search bar, moving bitmaps,
>   QuickActions, etc.)

The [Google I|O 2010 app](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/) is open source. How closely that app's implementation of the UI concepts meets the Twitter app's implementation of the same is unknown.