# Android Twitter App Source Code

Tags: android, open-source, twitter

I've been reading [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/twitter-for-android-closer-look-at.html) post on the android developer blog about the twitter client and UI patterns.

It mentions the source code will become available, does anyone know if this has happened yet and where I can find it? I've drawn a blank.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just asked the same question a few time ago:

[Good UI practice in Android, are there some sample code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219085/good-ui-practice-in-android-are-there-some-sample-code)

So, the answer is that Twitter source code is not available yet.

You may have a look at Google IO application that use similar tools or you can use the nice GreenDroid (http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=240) library while waiting Google to release the code.

Answer (score 0):

There was a post - on twitter, of course - a few days ago, saying that the source was coming very soon.  I can't find the post now, and Twitter doesn't seem to want to show me search results from before 1st August, but it was definitely a days-not-weeks type of message.